# System of 2nd-order ODE equations using Runge-Kutta

Tags: numerical-methods

Given the following system:
$$\begin{align}
u''_1(t)+u_1(t)+\frac{1}{3}u_2(t)&=0, \\
u''_2(t)-0.5u_1(t)+0.5u_2(t)&=2\sin(1.5t)
\end{align}$$
with the initial conditions $u_1(0)=u_2(0)=0$ and $u_1'(0)=u_2'(0)=0$, determine the response at $t=5$ using 4th-order Runge-Kutta equation with step size $h=0.01$.

How do I set up the recursion equation for this?

Comment: You write each as a system of first order equations and then follow http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146823/solving-coupled-2nd-order-odes-with-runge-kutta-4.

Comment: Did you also mean for the second equation to equal zero?